# Calculate Area of a Random Image in iPhone.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

These days i am working on an iPhone application.
The purpose of the application is to calculate area of any particular object captured by camera.For proper uniform objects i can calculate area quite easily by drawing an object over it and after width and height area if calculate.
My problem is to do the same work for a random image ,having many edges and corners.?
Can some help.Someone implemented any algo for it over iPhone.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Very old trick from the CAD  world: count the pixels.

Comment: My Image is like this..Any algorithm there through which i can calculate white area.Iamge not attached.:(

Comment: ...What about the trick to differentiate between less and more density of a screen? This way we can get that specific area.? Will it work for iPhone any Help

Answer (score 0):

this is working perfectly

hope to be helpful

```
[objImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[objImageView sizeToFit];       
NSLog(@"height -> %f",objImageView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"width -> %f",objImageView.frame.size.width);
```